# Understanding trivial functional dependency from Sailboat book

Tags: database, relational-database, database-schema, functional-dependencies

I'm reading the slides for Ch.7 of the Sailboat book: https://www.db-book.com/db7/slides-dir/PDF-dir/ch7.pdf and I've a hard time understanding what the authors mean by saying

> A functional dependency is **trivial** if it is satisfied by all
> instances of a relation.

The wording is very different from Wiki's one, which is quite easy to understand.

> A functional dependency FD: X → Y is called **trivial** if Y is a subset of X.

I tried looking at a worked example, but the condition "satisfied by all instances of a relation" really puzzles me.

Here's a relation taken from a university course:
http://web.cs.ucla.edu/classes/fall04/cs143/solutions/ch7.pdf

```
| A  | B  | C  |
|----|----|----|
| a1 | b1 | c1 |
| a1 | b1 | c2 |
| a2 | b1 | c1 |
| a2 | b1 | c3 |
```

In the solution for exercise 7.4, it's written that

> The nontrivial functional dependencies are: A → B and C → B ...

For me, the instances of the relation are all tuples in the table, and each of them satisfies all of the above quoted functional dependencies.  I don't understand why, using the Sailboat book's definition, that these functional dependencies aren't trivial.

Thanks for reading my question.

---

> 7.4 List all functional dependencies satisfied by the relation of Figure 7.21.
> Answer: The nontrivial functional dependencies are: A → B and C → B,
> Exercises 85
> and a dependency they logically imply: AC → B. There are 19 trivial functional dependencies of the form α → β, where β ⊆ α. C does not functionally
> determine A because the first and third tuples have the same C but different A
> values. The same tuples also show B does not functionally determine A. Likewise, A does not functionally determine C because the first two tuples have the
> same A value and different C values. The same tuples also show B does not
> functionally determine C.
> [image: fig 7.21]

Comment: Please put everything needed to ask your question in your post as text. Make your post self-contained. "instances of the relation are all tuples in the table" doesn't make sense. An instance of a relation variable is a   relation value, which is not a tuple value.

Comment: @philipxy What's missing in my post, apart from my flawed interpretation of relvar, which is not a standard term according to Wiki?  I've included relevant definitions, examples & sources.  Even if the PDF's are removed, the question can still be answered.

Comment: Please rephrase the quote in my comment, which doesn't make sense. Re being complete, you don't give all of exercise 7.4 or its solution, so it's not clear what you're saying about it.

Comment: @philipxy 1. As an advocator for MathJax in Linear Programming questions on Math.SE and the author for [this meta.SE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/327840/259305), I surely know which types of pictures are allowed on the SE network.  The inclusion of the screenshot is an illustrative purpose, and that's a dependency for the solution of exercise 7.4 that you've asked for.  It's fine without the screenshot, as I've already typed the table in the question context.  2. In the Sailboat book, it's stated "relation".  I can see nowhere in the book containing the term "relation variable".

Comment: SO does not use MathJax & is not math.se or any other SE site & neither of MathJax input nor output is an image. "Relvar" means "relation(-valued) variable" & "relation schema" typically means a set of attributes & sometimes a set of attributes with a relation name & applies to a relation value or variable & commonly when a schema is given an associated variable with those properties is assumed & "relation" can mean relation value or variable or schema. A "base relation" is a relation variable. PS Please don't shoot the messenger.

Comment: The point of my (prefab) comment re text/links/images here is, you don't need the image, because you gave it in text, and having it is redundant, since the text is just as readable. PS Also thanks, greetings & other social nicities are deprecated.

Comment: @philipxy Thx for answer.  I'm still reading & understanding it.  I get your point about the image, whose caption shows that it's really "Figure 7.21", not "Figure 7.64", or something else.  Googling "instance of a relation" with double quotes, I got "The relation instance is a table, An instance of a relation is a set of tuples, also called records, in which each tuple has the same number of fields as the relation schema." (from SoftCover.io) on top.

Comment: The quote in your comment uses "instance of a table/relation" to mean "particular value/state of a table/relation variable at a particular time/state". Sometimes  a relation value is a set of tuple/records; sometimes a bag; sometimes such a set/bag plus a heading that is essentially a schema or its attributes; etc. Depends on the presentation. Best to stick to your textbook definition & use of terms. Which sadly as this Q&A shows can nevertheless be quite sloppy. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts.) (Or slides.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We say that a FD (functional dependency) is satisfied (holds) in a given relation value iff/when what it states is true of the value. We say that a FD is satisfied (holds) in a given relation variable/schema iff/when it is satisfied (holds) in every value that can arise for it under given business rules.

Neither of your quotes gives a definition of when a FD is trivial in a given relation value or variable/schema, because they say "if" instead of iff/when. They only give a sufficient condition; they don't give a necessary & sufficient condition. So they don't tell you exactly when a FD is trivial for a given relation value or variable/schema.

They would be definitions if they said iff/when.

Let's take their "if" to mean iff/when.

"satisfied by all instances of a relation" is sloppy, unhelpful & misleading. It is phrasing meant to apply to a relation variable/schema. It is trying to say, would be satisfied even if you didn't know what constraints held, ie, would be satisfied even if no constraints held. It doesn't make much sense to use it given a relation value, since certain FDs do & don't hold for a given relation value at all times. (Clearly a value is constrained to be itself.)

A correct phrasing that applies to both variables/schemas & values is, satisfied given just the attributes, or, implied given just the attributes, or, able to be shown to be satisfied if all you knew were the attributes.

At the bottom of the slide it says

> In general, α → β is trivial if β ⊆ α

This isn't a definition either, for the same reason, namely (ab)using "if" when iff/when is intended. But taking "if" as iff/when, you get a definition. It is essentially the same phrasing as your 2nd quote, with α for X, β for Y & ⊆ for subset of.

So the trivial FDs in your example value are exactly the ones X → Y where Y ⊆ X. A → B & C → B are not of that form so they are not trivial FDs of that value.

The exercise then goes on to discuss the non-trivial FDs that hold, applying the definition of an FD holding to that relation value. Some non-trivial FDs hold & some don't. But the trivial ones must hold by definition; they are the ones that hold no matter what value you are given with given attributes.

Comment: I think I get it.  The Sailboat book should have added that word "variable" behind "relation" for clarity.  An instance of a relation variable is a relation value.  Whatever the tuple values are, there's a class of FDs which always hold trivially (due to set inclusions of subsets of attributes like Y ⊆ X).  We qualify those FDs as "trivial".

Comment: It should add "value" for clarity. It seems clear that the exercise talks about a relation value & that a letter+subscript is some value distinct from every other. If all you knew was that you had a variable that could hold that value then you could only infer that a FD not holding in the value doesn't hold in the variable; a FD holding in the value might not hold in the variable. If you were told that a variable's FDs were that value's FDs ... but you weren't. If you were told that the example table was a certain kind of pattern for values in a variable ... but you weren't.

Comment: A FD makes a certain statement about a relation value or variable. The trivial ones are definable via subset. But the motivation for that class is that it consists of the FDs whose statement is true given just the attributes. X → Y states that every time a given X subtuple value appears it is with the same Y subtuple value; that there is only one Y subtuple value per X subtuple value. For X={x1,...} & Y={y1, ...} it says EXISTS f f(x1,...)=(y1,...). The EXISTS is entailed by nothing iff/when Y ⊆ X. This leads to the subset definition.